# Type.getType() can't find the class

Tags: c#, null, gettype

I have a lot of static methods in a class, I want to get if a certain method is in the class X, and if it is, I want to invoke it. I checked with this:

```
if (Type.GetType("Homework.Homework.Functions").GetMethod(methodName) == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No such method.\nPress any key to restart the program");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                Main();
                return;
            }
            else
                Type.GetType("Homework.Homework.Functions").GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(null, parametersArray); // Invoking the method.
```

But it gives me a System.NullReferenceException in the line with the if() in it.

The starting of the program:

```
namespace Homework
{
class Homework
{
    static void Main()
    {
```

Declaration of the class:

```
public class Functions
    {
```

I probably should say that the class Functions is inside the class Homework.

How do I solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also note that declaring a class with the same name as its namespace is a really bad idea - and public nested types usually aren't a great idea either.

Comment: Why not just use `typeof(Homework.Homework.Functions)` ?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that nested types are separated with a `+` rather than a `.` in the IL name. If you write:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(global::Homework.Homework.Functions));
```

then you'll see the fully qualified name as far as the CLR is concerned.

So you want:

```
Type.GetType("Homework.Homework+Functions")
```

Assuming you *really* need to get it by name - avoid this sort of thing where possible. Use `typeof` wherever you know the type at compile-time (and are happy to have a reference if it's in a different assembly).

That will work if you're calling it from within the same assembly. If you're calling `Type.GetType` from a *different* assembly, you'll need to qualify the name with the assembly as well.

I'd also strongly encourage you [not to name a class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an assembly qualified name to `GetType(string)`. Instantiate your Homework class and look at its

```
GetType().FullName
```